# Excel web query 404 not found for site that exists

Tags: excel, vba, http-status-code-404, excel-web-query

I am trying to use Excel 2010 to get web data using the Get External Data > From Web

Excel is able to download data from (just checking the top left box to get the whole page)

http://accuscore.com/fantasy-sports/nfl-fantasy-sports/

but when you select RB to update the url to

http://accuscore.com/fantasy-sports/nfl-fantasy-sports/Rest-of-Season-RB

Excel web query says

> 'The internet site reports that the item you requested could not be found. (HTTP/1.0 404)'

Is there a work around because the website does exist!

Comment: show your code, please? You might have a typo or something.

Comment: I don't know what to show... From an empty excel sheet I select the 'web query' icon under Data tab and enter the url and click 'import'.. It works with the static web url.. not the slightly dynamic one.

Comment: ah, I see what you're saying... since this has the "vba" tag, I assumed you had actual vba code written down somewhere. Have you tried it without the http? seems like it shouldn't matter, but just in case there's maybe a redirect in there that excel can't handle or something....?

Comment: yeah, tried that.  The funny thing is Excel loads the webpage in its internal browser before I click Import.  Then as it is importing it can not find the page

Comment: Fiddler shows that this URL has a 404 return herader, but the content is also there. Don't know why they issue the 404 if it's a valid page. This http://serverfault.com/questions/252435/is-it-possible-to-get-404-errors-plus-content-back may be relevant (if not helpful), since the server seems to be Apache.